# How to add and delete a missing key value from one list to another

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, if-statement

I've been working with lists o better understand them. First of all, these data were gathered from a request call I made. I came across this idea of having two lists that have similar keys and values. `List one` has a dictionary that has a key `state: city` with two values, while `list two` has one of the values missing. On the other hand, `list two` has an extra value from one of the dictionary keys `state: city` not on `list one`. For the first piece of code, I want to update `list two` with the missing value from `list one`. For the second piece of code, I want to remove the extra value from `list two` that is missing on `list one`
This is what I have for the moment.

```
list_one = [
    {
        'name': 'California',
        'state': [{'id': '34567', 'city': 'LA'}, {'id': '67890', 'city': 'San Francisco'}],
        'region': 'W'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Texas',
        'state': [{'id': '45678', 'city': 'Austin'}],
        'region': 'SW'
    },
    {
        'name': 'New York',
        'state': [{'id': '56789', 'city': 'Brooklyn'}],
        'region': 'E'
    }
]

list_two = [
    {
        'name': 'California',
        'state': [{'id': '12345', 'city': 'Miami'}],
        'region': 'W'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Texas',
        'state': [{'id': '23456', 'city': 'Austin'}, {'id': '78901', 'city': 'Houston'}],
        'region': 'E'
    },
    {
        'name': 'New York',
        'state': [{'id': '01234', 'city': 'Brooklyn'}],
        'region': 'E'
    }
]


#update - if  list_one has cities not in list_two, add those
for state1 in list_one:
    for state2 in list_two:
        for city1 in state1['state']:
            for city2 in state2['state']:
            res = [i['state'] for i in list_one if i not in list_two]
                    if city1['city'] not in city2['city']:
                        city2['city'] = city1['city']

                #delete - if list_one doesn't have the city in list_two, delete it from 
                #list_two
                elif city2['city'] not in city1['city']:
                    old_city2 = city2
                    res2 = [i['state'] for i in list_two if i not in list_one]
                    # city2['city'].remove()
```

I feel I'm doing a bit too much and it might be simpler. As for the `id`, I don't want to update them only the `cities`. If I need to delete a `city then I would like to remove that whole dictionary element.

Thank you!

Comment: I understand you're trying to learn, but this layout is just begging for an SQL database.  If it were me, `list_one` would be a dictionary, where the key is the state name, and the value is a dict with `region` and a city ID, which gets looked up in a `cities` dictionary.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mention this, but this is from an API call. I just copied the data into python, so I can use it without having to request it. Although, I appreciate your comment, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the length of both lists is same:

```
 for i in range(len(list_one)):
        x = len(list_one[i]['state'])
        y = len(list_two[i]['state'])
        if x > y:
            print('Code to Update list 2')
        if y > x:
            print('Code to Remove data from list 2')
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Your two `if` conditions are the same.  And this doesn't really help very much, because you haven't shown how to do the update.

Comment: I managed to work it out. `if x > y` does work. Except that I only want the `city` to update. The `id` is updating as well, which I don't want. Now, I'm trying to see if I can set the new `id` equal to the old one.

Comment: The same goes for the `if y > x`, I got it working. I believe @saad_saeed mistyped it.

Answer (score 1):

Think about an arrangement like this instead, which has much less duplication of information:

```py
states1 = {
    'California': {
        'region': 'W',
        'cities': ['34567','67890']
    },
    'Texas': {
        'region': 'SW',
        'cities': ['45678']
    },
    'New York': {
        'region': 'E',
        'cities': ['56789']
    }
}

states2 = {
    'California': {
        'region': 'W',
        'cities': ['34567','67890']
    },
    'Texas': {
        'region': 'SW',
        'cities': ['45678']
    },
    'New York': {
        'region': 'E',
        'cities': ['56789']
    }
}

cities = {
     '34567': 'LA',
     '67890': 'San Francisco',
     '45678': 'Austin',
     '56789': 'Brooklyn',
     '12345': 'Miami',
     '23456': 'Austin',
     '78901': 'Houston',
     '01234': 'Brooklyn'
}
```